# Using user defined assemblies from Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2016, sqlps

I am trying to extract list of user defined assemblies through PowerShell for one of SQL Server administration for automation.
When I open SSMS and execute this query as

```
Select name, permission_set_desc 
From sys.assemblies
```

I am able to get the output as 2 rows as below

| Name | Permission_Set_Desc |
| --- | --- |
| Microsoft.SqlServer.Types | UNSAFE_ACCESS |
| StairwayToSQLCLR-02-Example | SAFE_ACCESS |

When I execute the same T-SQL through PowerShell using `Invoke-SQLCMD` command, I do not get any user defined assemblies rather only system defined assembly.

This is the command I used in PowerShell:

```
$query = "Select name, permission_Set_Desc from sys.assemblies"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -AbortOnError -OutputSQLErrors $true
```

I get the below only which is system defined assembly.

| Name | Permission_Set_Desc |
| --- | --- |
| Microsoft.SqlServer.Types | UNSAFE_ACCESS |

I am unable to get the user defined assemblies from PowerShell.

Did I miss something here?

Comment: Assemblies are deployed at database level. Are you sure you are connecting to the same database?

Comment: @AdamL, Thanks. I used the Database and I now I am able to retrieve both the rows.  Just to ask another help. Is there any way to automatically list user defined assemblies from all databases globally, instead of providing a db name or connecting to it. Basically, I am trying to automate SQL hardening control and part of it, I wanted to understand how many user defined assemblies exists in a SQL instance

Comment: I don't know any other way than to iterate all user databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vijayanand A said, assemblies are defined at database level. However, you can iterate all databases and display all of them with attached assemblies:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sql += 'SELECT '+
    QUOTENAME(DB.Name, '''') + ' COLLATE database_default db, '+
    'name COLLATE database_default name, '+
    'permission_set_desc COLLATE database_default permission_set_desc '+
  'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(DB.Name) + '.sys.assemblies UNION ALL '
FROM sys.databases DB

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql)-LEN(' UNION ALL'))

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Pawel Dyl, Very much thanks for this TSQL query, This query actually returns both system default assemblies and user defined assemblies. Is there anyway to restrict only printing out user defined assemblies? Please help

Comment: Microsoft.SqlServer.Types is the only system assembly I know. Just use WHERE clause to filter this entry.